# NSArrayController binding : Suppress "No selection"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have a texfield bound to an ArrayController. The controller key is "selection" because I select items from a NSTableView. But when there are no items in the table the textfield shows the gray text "no selection".

How can I suppress this text and have just an empty textfield?
Or how can I change the "No selection" text to something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the bindings inspector in Interface Builder, set the **No Selection Placeholder** to be a space character.